# Dataflow - Function not being called - Error - name not defined

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am working with Apache Beam on Google Dataflow and I'm calling a function sentiment through a lambda function and I get an error the the function name is not defined.

```
output_tweets = (lines
                     | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
                     | 'assign window key' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(10))
                     | 'batch into n batches' >> BatchElements(min_batch_size=49, max_batch_size=50)
                     | 'sentiment analysis' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: sentiment(x))
                     )
```

This was my Apache Beam call and in the last line function sentiment is mentioned which is giving me the problem.

The function code is as follows (which I don't think should matter):

```
def sentiment(messages):
    if not isinstance(messages, list):
        messages = [messages]

    instances = list(map(lambda message: json.loads(message), messages))
    lservice = discovery.build('language', 'v1beta1', developerKey = APIKEY)
    for instance in instances['text']:
        response = lservice.documents().analyzeSentiment(
            body ={
                'document': {
                    'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
                    'content': instance
                }
            }
        ).execute()
        instance['polarity'] = response['documentSentiment']['polarity']
        instance['magnitude'] = response['documentSentiment']['magnitude']

    return instances
```

I get the following traceback

```
  File "stream.py", line 97, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'sentiment' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-441']
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue can happen due to couple of reasons

1. Is the function `sentiment` definition present in the same python file as the beam pipeline.
2. Is the definition of function `sentiment` is before it it is called in the beam pipeline?

I did a quick test as below and if the both the above are followed it works as desired

```
def testing(messages):
    return messages.lower()

windowed_lower_word_counts = (windowed_words
                              | beam.Map(lambda word: testing(word))
                              | "count" >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement())

ib.show(windowed_lower_word_counts, include_window_info=True)

0   b'have'     3   2020-04-19 06:04:39.999999+0000 2020-04-19 06:04:30.000000+0000 (10s)   Pane 0
1   b'ransom'   1   2020-04-19 06:04:39.999999+0000 2020-04-19 06:04:30.000000+0000 (10s)   Pane 0
2   b'let'      1   2020-04-19 06:04:39.999999+0000 2020-04-19 06:04:30.000000+0000 (10s)   Pane 0
3   b'me'       1   2020-04-19 06:04:39.999999+0000 2020-04-19 06:04:30.000000+0000 (10s)   Pane 0
```

If the function is defined after it is called then we get the error as shown below

```
windowed_lower_word_counts = (windowed_words
                              | beam.Map(lambda word: testing_after(word))
                              | "count" >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement())

ib.show(windowed_lower_word_counts, include_window_info=True)

ERROR:apache_beam.runners.direct.executor:Exception at bundle <apache_beam.runners.direct.bundle_factory._Bundle object at 0x7f478f344820>, due to an exception.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 954, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 552, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "/root/apache-beam-custom/packages/beam/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1482, in <lambda>
    wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)]
  File "<ipython-input-19-f34e29a17836>", line 2, in <lambda>
    | beam.Map(lambda word: testing_after_new(word))
NameError: name 'testing_after' is not defined

def testing_after(messages):
    return messages.lower()
```

## UPDATE

Instead of passing the function as `beam.FlatMap(lambda x : fn(x))` pass the function as `beam.FlatMap(x)`

I believe in the first case beam tries to look for fn in the worker machines and it is not able to find it. The implementation details can be found here - https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fa4f4183a315f061e035d38ba2c5d4b837b371e0/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/core.py#L780

Comment: The function sentiment is in the same script and it's definition is before the pipeline run.

One thing I observed was that if I call the function without lambda and just using beam.Map, it reached the function. Any idea why?

Comment: If you look at https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fa4f4183a315f061e035d38ba2c5d4b837b371e0/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/core.py#L780 it shows that the user defined function should be one of 3 types `types.BuiltinFunctionType, types.MethodType, types.FunctionType`. Therefore just passing the function name is the right way to go about it and it is also mentioned in our examples. In the example that you have mentioned it is not able to find sentiment in the workers which you might have to pass inside a Class. If this was helpful do accept the answer.

Comment: Hey @jayadeep-jayaraman, this worked. But beam.Map also worked if the call is just `beam.Map(x)`.
Turns out, it gives me an error for `discovery.build` after that even though the library is imported. Not sure if this is the right place to ask about it.

Comment: Your update helped me fix my error. but I think it should be `beam.FlatMap(fn)` or for the original Q `beam.FlatMap(sentiment)` (or `testing` in your example) to make the answer more clear.